# can not configure sendmail send emails

Tags: php, email, sendmail

I have a `php` project that uses the `mail()` function. But emails are not sent so that I installed `sendmail`.

When I test `sendmail` through command line `echo "My test email being sent from sendmail" | /usr/sbin/sendmail -v mail@someemail.com`

then I get this message

```
WARNING: local host name (server) is not qualified;
...
server: Name server timeout
...
<mail@someemail.com>... Deferred: Name server: someemail.com.: host name lookup failure
```

So following some spots, I changed `/etc/hosts` adding this line

```
127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain myhostname.org
```

and even `/etc/hostnames` to add `myhostname.org`

But I still get the failure message, telling that the sender is `mymail@server.com` where it should be `mail@myhostname.org`

Comment: servername.com is not myhostname.org when you do `/usr/sbin/sendmail -v mymail@servername.com`

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions sorry I made a mistake, I have just edited my post.

Comment: Offtopic. This is server/dns configuration, which is not a programming issue.